# Verifying pip version for python 3.5.1 on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I installed python version 3.5.1 on Windows 7.  During the install I selected the option to install pip however, I have no idea how to verify that pip was actually installed.  I searched the site for answers to help but I was unsuccessful.  I apologize in advance if this question was asked. If the question was asked and you can point me to the specific post that would be great.  Just looking for some help.

Comment: Do you have this file on your PC `C:\PythonXY\Scripts\pip.exe`?

Comment: `py -m pip --version`, or if `py.exe` doesn't work `python -m pip --version`. This assumes that you checked the box to have python installed to the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open command prompt by typing `Win + R` and then type in `cmd`
then type
`py -m pip --version` or type `python -m pip --version`

This will output as `pip 8.1.2 from {Install Directory}\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)`

A note of warning though typing in `--v` won't work as there is confusion between `--verbose` and `--version`

Comment: This solution worked perfectly thank you for helping me with my question

Comment: @DeeR : Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip --version`

It should work.